# AWS SNS for time taken API calls

Tags: amazon-sns

Hi We subscribe the AWS SNS with our API service for guarantee execution and retry mechanism ,unfortunately our API call takes more than 30 sec to complete the task , as SNS waits for response less then 30 sec it treats as fail and reties the API again even my first API call is success after 30 sec, is there any way to increase the SNS response time like wait response to 2 or 3 mins or stop the retry of SNS dynamically or please suggest some other mechanism to run this background jobs with retry policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this type of use-case, you might want to consider publishing to a SQS queue from your SNS topic and then have your application poll from the queue to find jobs to execute. As SNS won't be calling your service directly, there is no timeout and you're free to take as much time as needed to complete the job.